# How to search for content from the Content Management admin view?

Tags: 6, nodes

This feels like such a dumb question to ask, but I can't find a way to search for my content on the Content Management view in the Administration area!

Could somebody point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 5):

In drupal 7 you can use the [Aministration Views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views).

It uses the Views module and [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to create some views to replace all the pages in administrtion area that does some kind of listing.

After the instalation you need enable the views created by this module.

For me this was the only way to get a "Title filter" for the contents in the drupal administration area.

Answer (score 3):

The core content management is quite limited. There are a few options:

1. There is a submodule in the [Admin menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) Module that replaces this with Views
2. There is a feature in [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) that does something similar to the above
3. Build your own view with an exposed search filter
4. There is also the [CMF](http://drupal.org/project/cmf) module that is an alternative to the Administer >> Content management >> Content tool with these additional options:

   Show nodes, comments or both
   Filter by author (select from drop-down list)
   Filter by author (enter username in AJAX search field)
   Filter by user role (shows nodes authored by any user in the selected role)
   Filter by user status (active or blocked)
   Filter by title or body substring
   Filter by node created date (before/after)
   Filter by node language
   Displays a column in the content list with node creation time
   Sort content list by any column: Title, Type, Author, Status, Time